# Convert code into a function in R

Tags: r, regex, text, rstudio

I have a series of steps that I will like to convert into a function, so I can apply it to data frames simply by calling them. Below is the code with some comments:

```
library("textreadr")
library("pdftools")   
library("tidyverse")
library("tidytext")    
library("textreadr")
library("tm")

# Create Data frame
Off_let_data <- data.frame(page_id = c(3,3,3,3,3), element_id = c(19, 22, 26, 31, 31), 
                                 text = c("The Protected Percentage of your property value thats has been chosen is 0%", 
                                          "The Arrangement Fee payable at complettion: £50.00", 
                                          "The Fixed Interest Rate that is applied for the life of the period is: 5.40%", 
                                          "The Benchmark rate that will be used to calculate any early repayment 2.08%", 
                                          "The property value used in this scenario is 275,000.00"))

# read in the first element of a list of pdf file from a folder
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")[1]

# extract the account number from the first pdf file
acc_num <- str_extract(files, "^\\d+")

# The RegEx's used to extract the relevant information
protec_per_reg <- "Protected\\sP\\w+\\sof"
Arr_Fee_reg <- "^The\\sArrangement\\sF\\w+"
Fix_inter_reg <- "Fixed\\sI\\w+\\sR\\w+"
Bench_rate_reg <- "Benchmark\\sR\\w+\\sthat"

# create a df that only includes the rows which match the above RegEx
Off_let <- Off_let_data %>% filter(page_id == 3, str_detect(Off_let_data$text, protec_per_reg)|
                                     str_detect(Off_let_data$text, Arr_Fee_reg) | str_detect(Off_let_data$text, Fix_inter_reg) | 
                                     str_detect(Off_let_data$text, Bench_rate_reg))

# Now only extract the numbers from the above DF
off_let_num <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+\\.?\\d+")

# The first element is always a NA value - based on the structure of these PDF files
# replace the first element of this character vector with the below
off_let_num[is.na(off_let_num)] <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+%")[[1]] 
off_let_num
```

Can someone please help me turning this into a function. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

What should be the inputs/outputs of the function? For now, the function only takes a data.frame as only argument, but you could extend it, so you can pass different regular expressions, or define the page_id for example.

```
library("textreadr")
library("pdftools")   
library("tidyverse")
library("tidytext")    
library("textreadr")
library("tm")

# Create Data frame
Off_let_data <- data.frame(page_id = c(3,3,3,3,3), element_id = c(19, 22, 26, 31, 31), 
                           text = c("The Protected Percentage of your property value thats has been chosen is 0%", 
                                    "The Arrangement Fee payable at complettion: £50.00", 
                                    "The Fixed Interest Rate that is applied for the life of the period is: 5.40%", 
                                    "The Benchmark rate that will be used to calculate any early repayment 2.08%", 
                                    "The property value used in this scenario is 275,000.00"))

dummyFunc <- function(df) {
  # read in the first element of a list of pdf file from a folder
  files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")[1]

  # extract the account number from the first pdf file
  acc_num <- str_extract(files, "^\\d+")

  # The RegEx's used to extract the relevant information
  protec_per_reg <- "Protected\\sP\\w+\\sof"
  Arr_Fee_reg <- "^The\\sArrangement\\sF\\w+"
  Fix_inter_reg <- "Fixed\\sI\\w+\\sR\\w+"
  Bench_rate_reg <- "Benchmark\\sR\\w+\\sthat"

  # create a df that only includes the rows which match the above RegEx
  Off_let <- df %>% filter(page_id == 3, str_detect(df$text, protec_per_reg)|
                                       str_detect(df$text, Arr_Fee_reg) | str_detect(df$text, Fix_inter_reg) | 
                                       str_detect(df$text, Bench_rate_reg))

  # Now only extract the numbers from the above DF
  off_let_num <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+\\.?\\d+")

  # The first element is always a NA value - based on the structure of these PDF files
  # replace the first element of this character vector with the below
  off_let_num[is.na(off_let_num)] <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+%")[[1]] 
  return(off_let_num)
}

dummyFunc(Off_let_data)
```

And for a more extended version of the function:

```
# The RegEx's used to extract the relevant information
protec_per_reg <- "Protected\\sP\\w+\\sof"
Arr_Fee_reg <- "^The\\sArrangement\\sF\\w+"
Fix_inter_reg <- "Fixed\\sI\\w+\\sR\\w+"
Bench_rate_reg <- "Benchmark\\sR\\w+\\sthat"

regexprlist <- list(protec_per_reg, Arr_Fee_reg,
                    Fix_inter_reg, Bench_rate_reg)

dummyFuncExt <- function(df, regexp, page_id) {
  # read in the first element of a list of pdf file from a folder
  files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")[1]

  # extract the account number from the first pdf file
  acc_num <- str_extract(files, "^\\d+")

  # create a df that only includes the rows which match the above RegEx
  Off_let <- df %>% filter(page_id == page_id, str_detect(df$text, regexprlist[[1]])|
                             str_detect(df$text, regexprlist[[2]]) | str_detect(df$text, regexprlist[[3]]) | 
                             str_detect(df$text, regexprlist[[4]]))

  # Now only extract the numbers from the above DF
  off_let_num <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+\\.?\\d+")

  # The first element is always a NA value - based on the structure of these PDF files
  # replace the first element of this character vector with the below
  off_let_num[is.na(off_let_num)] <- str_extract(Off_let$text, "\\d+%")[[1]] 
  return(off_let_num)
}

dummyFuncExt(df = Off_let_data, regexp = regexprlist, page_id = 3)
```

Comment: Yes something like this. Basically, I have over 200 pdf docs from which I want to extract certain pieces of information and then combine all these pieces into a data frame. The above code works on one pdf file at a time and gives me the relevant info in variable 'off_let_num'. Now I want to turn this code into a function so I can apply to all the pdf files in a folder and aggregate their results into a object that i will convert to a data frame at the end.

Comment: I will check this function tomorrow on the pdf files. Thanks for your help